# Having issues with the text yyy being displayed above image?

Tags: shopify

I dont know if anyone can help me, im getting yyy being displayed above our product images.
I have checked the code and I can see it lives in the DIV Image Wrap.

http://yogadesigned.com/collections/yoga-designed

yyy

I have checked all the code in the back and I cant find any yyy or ImageWrap.

Any suggestions how to get rid of this.

Comment: Go find your collection.liquid and find the wrapper in question ( it might be in a snippet ) and you remove the problem string.

Answer (score 0):

Somehow looks like you have edited one of your liquid files and you added yyy as text in this file.

It can be in the product file or in your collection file.
The files are located under the snippet folder of your theme.

```
Online Store > Themes > ... > Edit HTML/CSS
```

and now open the file which you edited and remove the yyy.
Since if appears on your home page it should be the collections template